# Call executable inside Nuget package cache from launchSettings.json

Tags: nuget-package, csproj

I created a small executable that is used to run and debug specific libraries from other solutions. The executable is given the path to a library as a command line argument which the executable loads at runtime.

I want to put my executable in a Nuget package, and have consuming libraries just add the Nuget package to be able to run and debug, using a launchSettings.json.

Because the executable is in the tools/ directory of the Nuget package, its path is put into the PATH environment variable by the Package Manger Console. Therefore the launchSettings can simply just call the executable.

I create my Nuget package with `nuget.exe pack my.nuspec -Version 1.0.0`, with my.nuspec containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>DebugHost</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>DebugHost</title>
    <authors>Some company</authors>
    <owners>Some company</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>DebugHost</description>
    <summary>DebugHost</summary>
    <copyright>2020, Some company</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\*" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

From consuming library projects I put in Properties\launchSettings.json containting:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "DebugHost": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "my.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)"
    }
  }
}
```

I have three different questions that are somewhat related, as any might answer another:

1. This setup only works as long as I keep the Package Manager Console opened. If I try to Debug / Launch the library without first opening the Package Manager Console, the launch fails because it cannot find the executable. `Unable to start program 'my.exe'. The system cannot fint the file specified.`

   Can I for example add a targets file in the Nuget package that will hint its path during build/launch, which in turn I can use as a variable in the launchSettings.json? (If so, how?)
2. This setup requires that a Properties\launchSettings.json is used in the consuming project. Can I make my Nuget package create that file?

   Can the file be an asset in the Nuget that gets copied to the correct place?

   Or can I even have an install.ps1 script that creates the json, with the correct absolute path to the executable in it? This would make question 1 answered as well.
3. The above situation only works with `nuget.exe pack` and a .nuspec.

   Can I instead move stuff into my (new style) .csproj and get this to work with just `dotnet.exe pack` and the .csproj? (or `msbuild.exe -t:pack` and the .csproj?) So ultimately I can also just create the package by simply right clicking the project in Visual Studio and selecting Pack from the context menu?

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this? - I'm in similar situation wondering about a NuGet package that interacts with launchsettings.json.